# Why is an align attribute propagating from td to a contained table on IE only?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html-table, alignment

This html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head><title>TD align test</title></head>
<body>
<table width="100%">
  <tr><td>aligned left</td><td align="right">aligned right</td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="2" align="center">
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr><td>should be aligned left</td></tr>
    </table>
  </td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

aligns the "should be aligned left" centered in IE (6 & 8) and Opera, but to the left in Firefox (3.6 & 4 beta) and Chromium.  The former seem to propagate the alignment from the td to the contained table.

Can anyone explain this difference?  And which behavior is more standards-compliant?

(You can try it at http://ysth.info/tdalign.html.)

Comment: Is this just a case study ? because you do not have to align center, when the contents are 100% wide. But the issue is indeed interesting.

Comment: @Gaby: yes, this is just a simple case demonstrating the effect.  I'd like to know the forces at play here to make it possible to find all the similar problems in a large body of table-happy code, not just the readily apparent problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at http://www.docsteve.com/DocSteve/TechNotes/IE6_cascade_test.html for why it *might* be happening.

The fact is that it is another IE *glitch* (*incompatibility with other browsers*) . Only thing i can suggest is to override it, by explicitly specifying the alignment you want..

If you use classes and the `text-align:center` you will notice that all browsers behave as IE does with the `align` attribute, so not sure which is correct/wrong with that.

Comment: Hmm.  would `table { text-align:left }` be a generic fix?  (I have no th elements)

Comment: @ysth, yes but combined with `td{text-align:inherit;}`, it should cover all cases. But you will need to use a `class` or the `style` attribute to override it as the `align="left"` will not work (*it gets overridden by those rules*)

Comment: I didn't get that last part; can you clarify, perhaps with an example?

Comment: if you do not make the `td` inherit the `text-align` of its parent element (the `table`) it will use its default value, which causes the effect you mentioned in your original post. You could also use directly a `td{text-align:left}` to target just the `td` elements and skip the table one completely.

Answer (score 1):

The align attribute is [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/graphics.html#h-15.1.2), so even if I knew how to manage it, I wouldn't feel comfortable trying to negotiate it as newer browsers may have more and more trouble displaying it consistently.

For your case, you may want to just define classes `.right` and `.left` (to override a cascading `.right`) and tack them onto the rows, tables, or cells as you see fit.

Comment: deprecated should not be a problem; deprecated just means user agents that only support future html versions may no longer support it, it does *not* mean that user agents that purport to support 4.01 have carte blanche to break deprecated things.  That said, the html5 draft does remove align, and the very fact that it is deprecated indicates that there are good reasons not to use it.